# How do I do calculations with data from another table using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am in the process of doing some research that has me running analysis in a few separate `df`.  The results of the separate `df` are to be used in one main calculation `df`.  Most of the stat categories are used in several `df`.  I'm looking to use the results from the separate `df`

```
# Table used for league average calculations below
teams <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Team,  ~PA,  ~AB,   ~H, ~HBP, ~BB, ~HR,  ~R, ~RBI, ~SB,  ~AVG,  ~OBP,
  "Athletics", 6255, 5579, 1407,   76, 550, 227, 813,  778,  35, 0.252, 0.325,
  "Red Sox", 6302, 5623, 1509,   55, 569, 208, 876,  829, 125, 0.268, 0.339,
  "Yankees", 6271, 5515, 1374,   62, 625, 267, 851,  821,  63, 0.249, 0.329,
  "Indians", 6300, 5595, 1447,   80, 554, 216, 818,  786, 135, 0.259, 0.332,
  "Astros", 6146, 5453, 1390,   61, 565, 205, 797,  763,  71, 0.255, 0.329
)


# Table used for player calculations (main table)
players <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Name,     ~Team,  ~G, ~PA, ~AB,  ~H, ~HBP, ~BB, ~HR,  ~R, ~RBI, ~SB,  ~AVG,  ~OBP,
  "Mookie Betts", "Red Sox", 136, 614, 520, 180,    8,  81,  32, 129,   80,  30, 0.346, 0.438,
  "Mike Trout",  "Angels", 140, 608, 471, 147,   10, 122,  39, 101,   79,  24, 0.312,  0.46,
  "J.D. Martinez", "Red Sox", 150, 649, 569, 188,    4,  69,  43, 111,  130,   6,  0.33, 0.402,
  "Alex Bregman",  "Astros", 157, 705, 594, 170,   12,  96,  31, 105,  103,  10, 0.286, 0.394,
  "Jose Ramirez", "Indians", 157, 698, 578, 156,    8, 106,  39, 110,  105,  34,  0.27, 0.387
)


# Denominators needed for calculations
calc_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~data_col, ~calc_denom,
  "HR",        14.3,
  "R",        19.6,
  "RBI",        17.5,
  "SB",        26.2,
  "AVG",      0.0045,
  "OBP",      0.0031
) %>% 
  spread(key = data_col, value = "calc_denom")


# Get league average of teams
lg_avg <- teams %>% 
# Divide counting stats by 10 to get the averages for 10 batters
  mutate_at(vars(PA:SB), funs(./10)) %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

lg_avg
#> # A tibble: 1 x 11
#>      PA    AB     H   HBP    BB    HR     R   RBI    SB   AVG   OBP
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  625.  555.  143.  6.68  57.3  22.5  83.1  79.5  8.58 0.257 0.331

# Calculate Values
value_tbl <- players %>% 
  mutate(calc_R = R / calc_tbl$R,
         calc_HR = HR / calc_tbl$HR,
         calc_RBI = RBI / calc_tbl$RBI,
         calc_SB = SB / calc_tbl$SB,
         calc_BA = (((lg_avg$H * 13 ) + H)/(AB + (lg_avg$AB * 13)) - lg_avg$AVG) / calc_tbl$AVG,
         calc_Total = (calc_R + calc_HR + calc_RBI + calc_SB + calc_BA))
```

I really have 2 questions, and both focus on efficiency, and whether there is a better way to do what I'm doing.  Am I calling the results from the other `df` column calculations properly?
Is there a more direct, and efficient way to write the last piece of code on the mutates?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you (using `data.table`):

```
# load packages
library(data.table)

# Table used for league average calculations below ----
teams <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Team,  ~PA,  ~AB,   ~H, ~HBP, ~BB, ~HR,  ~R, ~RBI, ~SB,  ~AVG,  ~OBP,
  "Athletics", 6255, 5579, 1407,   76, 550, 227, 813,  778,  35, 0.252, 0.325,
  "Red Sox", 6302, 5623, 1509,   55, 569, 208, 876,  829, 125, 0.268, 0.339,
  "Yankees", 6271, 5515, 1374,   62, 625, 267, 851,  821,  63, 0.249, 0.329,
  "Indians", 6300, 5595, 1447,   80, 554, 216, 818,  786, 135, 0.259, 0.332,
  "Astros", 6146, 5453, 1390,   61, 565, 205, 797,  763,  71, 0.255, 0.329
)
setDT(teams) # set df as data.table

# Table used for player calculations (main table) -----
players <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Name,     ~Team,  ~G, ~PA, ~AB,  ~H, ~HBP, ~BB, ~HR,  ~R, ~RBI, ~SB,  ~AVG,  ~OBP,
  "Mookie Betts", "Red Sox", 136, 614, 520, 180,    8,  81,  32, 129,   80,  30, 0.346, 0.438,
  "Mike Trout",  "Angels", 140, 608, 471, 147,   10, 122,  39, 101,   79,  24, 0.312,  0.46,
  "J.D. Martinez", "Red Sox", 150, 649, 569, 188,    4,  69,  43, 111,  130,   6,  0.33, 0.402,
  "Alex Bregman",  "Astros", 157, 705, 594, 170,   12,  96,  31, 105,  103,  10, 0.286, 0.394,
  "Jose Ramirez", "Indians", 157, 698, 578, 156,    8, 106,  39, 110,  105,  34,  0.27, 0.387
)
setDT(players) # set df as data.table

# Denominators needed for calculations----
calc_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~data_col, ~calc_denom,
  "HR",        14.3,
  "R",        19.6,
  "RBI",        17.5,
  "SB",        26.2,
  "AVG",      0.0045,
  "OBP",      0.0031
)
setDT(calc_tbl) # set df as data.table

# Get league average of teams ----
lg_avg <- teams[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = T), .SDcols = which(sapply(teams, is.numeric))] # summarize by columns that are numeric

# Calculate Values
cols <- names(players)[-c(1:2)] # assign an object with the column names to be calculated

res <- copy(players) # optional: I am making a copy of "players" because the `:=` operator changes the data by reference. If don't need to preserve the players table, then you don't need to make a copy, replace res in the loop and in the data.table::melt(...) expression by "players".

    for(i in cols){
  if(i == "OBP"){
    res[, (i) := (lg_avg$OBP * lg_avg$PA) + H + BB]
    next
  }
  res[, (i) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    if(is.null(lg_avg[[i]])) return(NA)
    return(x/lg_avg[[i]])
    }), .SDcols= i]
}

res <- data.table::melt(res, id.vars = c(1:2), variable.name = "stat_value", value.name = "calc_column")
```

Partial result:

```
> head(res)
            Name    Team stat_value calc_column
1:  Mookie Betts Red Sox          G          NA
2:    Mike Trout  Angels          G          NA
3: J.D. Martinez Red Sox          G          NA
4:  Alex Bregman  Astros          G          NA
5:  Jose Ramirez Indians          G          NA
6:  Mookie Betts Red Sox         PA  0.09816461
```

Comment: @Jazzmatazz are you looking for a `tidyverse` solution only?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it seems like you just need to apply a different formula based on the value of `data_col`? So why not just add an `if_else` in your `mutate` call, e.g.,

UPDATED

```
value_tbl <- players %>% 
  gather(key = data_col, value = "stat_value", -c(Name, Team)) %>% 
  left_join(calc_tbl, by = "data_col") %>% 
  # Join on players table and drop Team so there's no column duplication
  left_join(players %>% select(-Team), by = "Name") %>%
  mutate(calc_column = if_else(data_col == 'OBP', lg_avg$OBP * lg_avg$PA + H + BB ,stat_value / calc_denom))
```

Comment: The issue with OBP is that I need each rows H and BB before I gather to long.

Comment: Ok, so you need to use H and BB from the `players` rather than from `lg_avg`?

Comment: The exact formula is: (((League Average OBP * League Average PA) * 12) + H + BB + HBP) / (AB + BB + HBP) – League Average OBP / calc_tbl OBP

The H, BB, HBP, AB columns all come from the `players` `df`, the league average results all come from `league_avg`, and the calc_denoms all come from the calc_tbl.

Comment: So it seems like just joining on `players` will allow you to access those variables per player. I've edited the answer above, which I think will give you what you need unless I'm still misunderstanding.

Comment: I guess another join is a viable solution, was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: Is it easier to just do all of the calculations in a wide data frame?  If so, how would I achieve my desired result?